# What type of blocks/items can't you obtain by trading?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What are the items/blocks, that are considered *unrenewable*, that you cannot obtain by trading with villagers?

Comment: the wiki has [a list of all trades](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Trade#Possible_offers)

Comment: This changes too often to have a right answer. Used to be that netherbrick was a non-renewable resource, but now it's craftable. That pattern has repeated very many times in Minecraft's history.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie i vote to leave it open as almost everything in minecraft has changed at some point in time. Saying that the upcoming changes will for sure change unrenewable items to renewable items is purely speculation. even if it is probably correct

Comment: Well, stuff like bedrock, ender portals, spawn eggs, spawners, that kind of stuff. What exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made this: http://www.reddit.com/tb/193bu9. It is a list of all recources, labled with which ones are renewable and how to get them.

The unrenewable ones are:

- Dirt and Grass
- Bedrock
- Lava
- Sand
- Gravel
- All Ore
- Sponge
- Glass
- Lapis Block
- Sandstone
- Cobweb
- Dead Bush
- Slabs and stairs except Cobblestone, Wooden, Stone Bricks
- Bricks
- TNT
- Mossy Stone
- Mob Spawner
- Diamond Block
- Tilled Land
- Clay
- Jukebox
- Netherrack
- Soul Sand
- Mycelium
- Lilies
- Nether Brick Fence
- Enchanting Table
- End Portal Frame
- End Stone
- Dragon Egg
- Beacon
- Daylight Sensor
- Quartz Block
- Coal
- Diamond

Comment: Correction: Coal *is* renewable, as of 1.4.2, they are dropped by Wither Skeletons

Answer (score 1):

One of my favorite minecraft websites minecraft.net has [this article](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Trading) talking about all of the possible trades.

Here is a picture that sums up the trades
[image]